# Setting screwturn domain / base directory

Tags: configuration, screwturn

I've set up an internal screwturn wiki for our company on **http://mywikiip/mywikiname.** It works, however when you click **login** the login page has a redirect value in the url which points to **http://web/mywikiname** which then, understandably, takes the user to a 404 page.

Does anyone know how to config this properly?

Comment: it seems to be using the same wrong domain when I autodetect the domain when configuring the site outgoing emails, I think it's a domain/iis issue. anyone know a work around?